# Mismatching the version of OpenCV inside of the OpenFrameworks

Tags: opencv, openframeworks

I want to use OpenCv's dnn::Net class inside of the openFrameworks.

I checked the version of the openCV in openFrameworks by printing out CV_VERSION and etc, which was 3.1.0.

I looked up the openCV documentation of 3.1.0 and found out that 3.1.0 supports dnn::Net class.

However, when I tried to use cv::dnn::Net in openFrameworks, it says cv has no module called dnn.

Any kind of advise or insights would be really appreciated.

```
cout << "OpenCV version : " << CV_VERSION << endl;
cout << "Major version : " << CV_MAJOR_VERSION << endl;
cout << "Minor version : " << CV_MINOR_VERSION << endl;
cout << "Subminor version : " << CV_SUBMINOR_VERSION << endl;

cv::dnn::Net net
```

Answer (score 0):

Early opencv_dnn was not in the mainOpenCV, it was in opencv_contrib modules. But in all cases I recommend to use dnn from lates OpenCV version: it fixed a lot of errors and added new NN architectures.